# Failed to run the npm install

Tags: angular, windows, npm-install

I am getting the following error when I try to run the npm install.

```
D:\Startup\AmBlock\AmBlockApp>npm i      
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @amcharts/amcharts3-angular@3.0.2
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@12.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~12.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"12.0.3" from @angular/animations@12.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"~12.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/animations@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/material@12.0.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^12.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     2 more (@angular/platform-browser, @swimlane/ngx-charts)
npm ERR!   13 more (@angular/cdk, @angular/common, @angular/flex-layout, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^12.2.0 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0" from @amcharts/amcharts3-angular@3.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts3-angular
npm ERR!   @amcharts/amcharts3-angular@"^3.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@14.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^12.2.0 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0" from @amcharts/amcharts3-angular@3.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts3-angular
npm ERR!     @amcharts/amcharts3-angular@"^3.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-04T07_43_43_807Z-debug-0.log
```

I try to install node_module. I want the node_module folder in my angular project.

Comment: I sometimes have a hard time reading these, but it looks like it is asking for angular `12.2.0` or greater but you have `12.0.x` as per this line: `peer @angular/core@"^12.2.0 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0" from @amcharts/amcharts3-angular@3.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation or google bro.

```
npm i something
```

to install "something" package.

so you type `npm i` that is wrong syntax.

Comment: Actually, there is another way to install the package. Add the package name in package.json file and command 'npm i' will install it.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue with the unsupported version of the package "@amcharts/amcharts3-angular@3.0.2", you need to update it to the latest version. To do this, please run the following command in your terminal/command prompt:

`npm install @amcharts/amcharts3-angular --save`

This will install the latest version of the package, which should work with Angular 12.